# Can flooring accelarator damage car in any way?

Tags: acceleration

I have a hyundai coupe 2006.  Recently I started flooring the accelartor(push pedal right down to floor in an instant) to make car go faster.

When I accelerate smoothly and slowly I notice the car sounds nice and smooth while it picks up speed.  However when I floor the accelerator it sounds dodgy and not smooth at all.  Is it OK to floor the accelerator in way described or might it lead to car damage?

Comment: Most cars are not smooth when accelerating that hard. You will notice the transmission shifting, whereas when you are accelerating gently you will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Car damage" is not very descriptive, but I'm going to try and answer the question I *think* you're getting at, which is "Are there negative effects from constantly flooring it?"  To which the answer is: yes.

In short, you are going to "wear through" everything faster.  Some examples:

- Tires will burn up faster, and you will get less life out of them.
- Suspension and drivetrain components are getting a sudden "jolt" applied to them, which will reduce life.
- You are asking your transmission to shift at higher RPMs on a regular basis, which can and will accelerate wear.
- And of course, you are going to get worse gas mileage.
- Also all of that quick accelerating likely means excessive braking, so you will be eating through pads/rotors faster.

Now don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that you should never try to accelerate quickly or risk your car falling apart.  Cars are built to be driven.  But I don't really understand this part of your post:

> Recently I started flooring the accelartor(push pedal right down to floor in an instant) to make car go faster.

The question really is, why are you doing this?  Are you trying to merge onto the freeway at the appropriate speed, and as such you pin your foot to the floor for 5 seconds?  If so, go for it, it's safer to merge at the same speed as everyone else.

But if you are just flooring it every time the light turns green, only to slam on your brakes and get stuck in traffic 20 seconds later... I'd question what benefit you are really getting.  You aren't saving time, and you are costing yourself money.

Answer (score 0):

Prolonged flooring as you put it may cause some harm. But driving/accelerating hard shouldn't cause an issue. If you do this with a cold engine (just started) then you might have a problem or if your engine has high mileage on it.

What do you mean by "dodgy"?

It will sound a little more noisy. Not smooth may be a misfire.

Is it an inline 4 cylinder or a V6?

Comment: Dodgy is probably what you described 'noisy, not smooth, misfire'.  Its a 4 cylinder. sorry whats the difference between accelerating hard and what I described. what do you mean by prolonging? i was describing how I take it down in an instant and keep it there, are you saying the flooring isnt a problem but keeping it down for too long is?  If so how long is too long? thanks

Comment: If you "floor it" most times when you take off then this will cause more wear on your engine over time. It won't kill your engine.